# Arduino simultaneous push button for a counter

Tags: arduino-uno, button, input

I am a newbie with arduino. I am trying to have a counter with 3 buttons. Each Button when pressed will increase the number of counts. The counter should still count if button 2 is pressed while button 1 has not been released, and button 3 should also be able to increase the counter even if button 2 and button 1 are still pressed.

My code below counts if only one button is pressed at a time.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
int pbutton1 = 2;
int pbutton2 = 3;
int pbutton3 = 4;
int count = 0;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode (pbutton1, INPUT);
  pinMode (pbutton2, INPUT);
  pinMode (pbutton3, INPUT);

  lcd.print("My Counter");
}

void loop() {

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Total ");
  if (digitalRead(pbutton1) == HIGH) {
    lcd.print(count++);
    while (digitalRead(pbutton1) == HIGH); //monitor button to avoid continous count
  }

  if (digitalRead(pbutton2) == HIGH) {
    lcd.print(count++);
    while (digitalRead(pbutton2) == HIGH); //monitor button to avoid continous count
  }

  if (digitalRead(pbutton3) == HIGH) {
    lcd.print(count++);
    while (digitalRead(pbutton3) == HIGH); //monitor button to avoid continous count
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (digitalRead(pbutton1) == HIGH);` This blocks execution so nothing else can happen while the button is pressed. To avoid continous updating of the var while the button is pressed, create 3 booleans that keep track of the button state.

```cpp
bool button1_is_pressed = false;
....
// If the button is pressed AND it was not previously pressed
if (digitalRead(pbutton1) == HIGH && !button1_is_pressed) {
    button1_is_pressed = true;
    lcd.print(count++);
}
// Not pressed - reset state variable
else if (digitalRead(pbutton1) == LOW) {
    button1_is_pressed = false;
}
```

Do this for the other buttons as well.

Comment: Hi! @Johnny, I have tried your code, it however gives a continuous count for as long as the button is pressed. In fact, a single push of the button already gives you like 38 on the counter, and not +1

Comment: @Kidd Could be a [debouncing](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce) issue.  I'll test it here and see what results I get...

Comment: Thank you, I shall wait for your feedback, in the meantime. I will play around and see how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I tested and had some minor issues with debouncing. Adding `delay(10)` to the end of `loop()` fixed it. Also, not sure how you are wired, but if you have your buttons wired directly to a pin, you should use the built in pullup resistors: `pinMode (pbutton1, INPUT_PULLUP);`

Comment: I have the buttons connected to 1k ohms resistors then connected to the pins on the arduino

Comment: @Kidd The Arduino's internal pullup resistors are 10K. Maybe try that, as the code works fine for me.

Comment: I am able to handle the debouncing now with the delay. But keeping the button pressed still gives a continuous count.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this using the PushButton library. If buttons are pressed simultaneously, the count still sums up when the button is released.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Pushbutton.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
int count = 0;

#define button1 14
#define button2 15
#define button3 16

Pushbutton pbutton1(button1);
Pushbutton pbutton2(button2);
Pushbutton pbutton3(button3);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("My Counter");
}

void loop() {

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Total ");
    if (pbutton1.getSingleDebouncedPress()){
      count = count + 1; //increase the counter once the button is released
    }
    if (pbutton2.getSingleDebouncedPress()){
      count = count + 1; //increase the counter once the button is released
    }
    if (pbutton3.getSingleDebouncedPress()){
      count = count + 1; //increase the counter once the button is released
    }

  lcd.print(count);
}
```